# ngx-progressbar can't run bar when i used in http request

Tags: angular, progress-bar

I try the demo code "https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-progressbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts". On this website is success.

Then I take this demo code to my project. why can't i see progress bar when i use http requests?

```
<ng-progress #progressBar (started)="onStarted()" (completed)="onCompleted()" 
    [color]="options.color" 
    [speed]="options.speed" 
    [spinner]="options.spinner" 
    [spinnerPosition]="options.spinnerPosition" 
    [trickleSpeed]="options.trickleSpeed" 
    [ease]="options.ease">
</ng-progress>

<button (click)="testHttp()">hihihihi
</button>

import { NgProgress } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';

startedClass = false;
completedClass = false;

options = {
            minimum: 0.08,
            maximum: 1,
            ease: 'linear',
            speed: 200,
            trickleSpeed: 300,
            meteor: true,
            spinner: true,
            spinnerPosition: 'right',
            direction: 'leftToRightIncreased',
            color: 'red',
            thick: true
          };
        onStarted() {
            this.startedClass = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.startedClass = false;
            }, 800);
        }

        onCompleted() {
            this.completedClass = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.completedClass = false;
            }, 800);
}

testHttp() {
    this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/usersdelay=2').subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    });
}

constructor(public router: Router ,private http: Http ,public progress: NgProgress) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any error message ??

If yes, please attach the error message

Comment: No any error message.  I can get  console.log(res);

Comment: You meant there is nothing printed in the console.log output ??

Comment: Yes, so I don't know why it can't run.

Comment: Can you push your code to stack-blitz, I'll try to test and check what's the issue !

Comment: I have managed to make the code work, I have put the code in ngOnInit(), now we can see the json response. Please click on the success button and you'll see the progressbar